# Body field should already be filled when the node is created

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I would like to have a bodyfield already filled in when I create the node. Unfortunately this is a lot of text in html, so I can't solve this with the https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate module.

But I would like to build a small mini-module for this. I would like to drag the content from another node via nid and copy it into the body field of the node I am creating.

For this I would like to use the hook_entity_create Hook. Am I basically correct? My program looks like this at the moment:

```
<?php

use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_prepare_form() for node entities.
 */
function copy_fields_from_model_contract_node_create_node_create(NodeInterface $node)
{
//TODO Build NID as array and go through with loop

  $nid = 6766;
  $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $node = $node_storage->load($nid);

  if ($nid == '6766') {
    $getcontract = $node->field_vertragsinhalt->value;
  }

  //TODO Works without ($operation == 'default')

  if ($node->getType() == 'mustervertrage') {
    /*dpm ($node->field_vertragsinhalt->value);*/
    //TODO Shall always pull the current node and nid. But does not work yet with node creation. Error: Call to a member function id() on null in

    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $nid = $node->id();
    $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
    $node = $node_storage->load($nid);


      dpm($nid);
      $node->field_vertragsinhalt->value = $getcontract;
      $node->body->format = 'full_html';
      // don't save the node yet, it will be saved after submitting

  }
}
```

I then get the following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function id() on null in copy_fields_from_model_contract_node_create() (line 29 of modules/custom/copy_fields_from_model_contract_node_create/copy_fields_from_model_contract_node_create.module).
```

But this means that at the moment of the creation of the node there is no ID yet, right? But how can I then write in the field, have I overlooked something. So the hook seems to work, but how do I get my content in there?

Thanks Bavra

Comment: Which hook function do you call `copy_fields_from_model_contract_node_create_node_create()` in?

Comment: I wanted to use this hook: function hook_entity_create

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_create/8.2.x

But I'm just seeing for myself that I've missed something. Doesn't it have to be called that way:
function hook_entity_create(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)

But is that the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `hook_entity_create()` or `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create()`, the `$node->id()` will be null because these hook are invoked before the node is actually saved to the database.

You should use `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()` which is called after the node has been saved:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()
 */
function <your_module>_node_insert(NodeInterface $node) {
  if (<some conditions to get the node you want>) {
    // your logic
    $node->save();
  }
}
```